# How to call C# app / .exe from SSMS script to run locally, not on server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, external

I want to plot various columns from my DBs.

There does not appear to be a simple way to do this from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), so I have created a small C# app that takes a table name and column name and does the plotting.

I would like to call this from SSMS, within the .sql file, with something like:

```sql
EXEC "C:\\MyPlotApp.exe [dbo].[Table] ColA"
```

I found `xp_cmdshell` BUT this appears to execute on the server, I want to execute locally.

I can create an External Tool pointing to my App.exe (even though this cannot be executed directly from the SQL script). As a parameters I list `$(CurText)` which passes in my string. Only problem is that there is no parameter options to pass in table name and cursor column position from Results window.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Sounds like you are going on the wrong road

Comment: I want to be able to plot columns from my table quickly and easily

Answer (score 1):

SSMS supports `SQLCMD` mode (Query-->SQLCMD Mode). This allows you to use [SQLCMD commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#sqlcmd-commands) within the SSMS query window, including the `!::` command  to launch an external program on the client  synchronously. For example:

```
:!! C:\MyPlotApp.exe "[dbo].[Table]" "ColA"
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of this feature ! Did you made a typo in your answer ? `!::` instead of `:!!`

Comment: @Cid, yea, typo. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Thanks for this. Actually, I found an easy way. I just create an External Tool pointing to my App.exe. As a parameters I list $(CurText) which pases in my string. Only niggle is that there is no parameter options to pass in table name and cursor column position from Results window

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to pass in Results tab values to external tools, as far as I can tell. There are only three options that I can think of at the moment:

1. Set up your external tool C# app to read from the clip board. Then, in the "Results Grid", select the column and hit <kbd>Control-C</kbd> (this will copy all values to the clipboard). Then, launch your external app which will read that list of values from the clip board and plot them. Not sure how many rows you are working with, but it *might* be an issue if hundreds of thousands / millions. I guess it depends on how much available RAM your workstation has.
2. Technically, you don't really need SSMS to execute the query just so that you can pass the results to another app. Your C# app can execute the query and read the result rows directly.
3. If you want actual access to the "Results" Grid values, then you need to write your own SSMS extension. Do a search on creating your own extension as there are few tutorials out there.